# (Rails 4.2) How to trigger scaffold generation from View?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-generators

How can I trigger a scaffold generation from a view?

For example, let's say I have a method like this:

```
def scaffold_generation
  system "rails g scaffold TodoList task author"
end
```

How can I make a button on my "example_page.html.erb" trigger this method to execute the command on the server? (No worries about security here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1:**  Create a form using [Form Tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

```
<%= form_tag('/create_scaffold') do -%>
  <div><%= submit_tag 'Create Scaffold' %></div>
<% end %>
```

**2:** Write a routes to match the incoming request.

```
 match '/create_scaffold', to: 'examples#scaffold_generation', via: :all
```

**3:**

```
class ExamplesController < ApplicationController

   def scaffold_generation
      system "rails g scaffold TodoList task author"
      system "rake db:migrate" #=> use this so that, it won't throw any errors.
      render :text => "Whoa !!! Done"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a button or link it should be pointed to a url path not just a helper method. A quick fix for this is add a path to the helper method.

So you can try

in helper

```
def scaffold_generation(url)
  system "rails g scaffold TodoList task author"
  url
end
```

and in view

```
<%= button_to "Scaffold Generation", scaffold_generation(root_path), :method => :get %>
```